# pyqt - error while running, probably wrong paintevent method implementation

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

Me and my colleagues are writing a data processing application in python.
We are currently working on the frontend part of the application.

We have a big problem though, that's that the application gets the following error after a random amount of time:

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
```

This one also pops up from time to time:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

This is the file where all gui related stuff happens, I cut out the irrelevant methods for the sake of not being to lengthy:

gfx.py:

```
import sys, random, math

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from random import randrange

from eventbased import listener

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def exec():
    return app.exec_()

class MapView(QtGui.QMainWindow, listener.Listener):
    def __init__(self, mapimagepath = 0, nodes = 0):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        listener.Listener.__init__(self)


        self.setWindowTitle('Population mapping')
        self.map = Map(self, mapimagepath)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.map)

        self.map.start()
        self.center()


    def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move(50, 0)


    def handle(self, event):
        if(event.type == 0):
            self.map.addNode(event.object.scanner)
        if(event.type == 1):
            self.map.delNode(event.object.scanner)
        if(event.type == 2):
            self.map.addBranch(event.object.node1.scanner, event.object.node2.scanner)
        if(event.type == 3):
            self.map.delBranch(event.object.node1.scanner, event.object.node2.scanner)
        if(event.type == 4):
            self.map.changeNode(event.object.scanner.sensorid, event.result)
        if(event.type == 5):
            self.map.changeBranch(event.object.node1.scanner.sensorid, event.object.node2.scanner.sensorid, event.result)


        self.repaint(self.map.contentsRect())
        self.update(self.map.contentsRect())



######################################################################

class Map(QtGui.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, mapimagepath):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)

        #self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

        #coordinaten hoeken NE en SW voor kaart in map graphics van SKO 
        self.realmap = RealMap( 
            mapimagepath,
            (51.0442, 3.7268), 
            (51.0405, 3.7242),
            550, 
            800)

        parent.setGeometry(0,0,self.realmap.width, self.realmap.height)
        self.refreshspeed = 5000

        self.mapNodes = {}

    def addNode(self, scanner):
        coord = self.realmap.convertLatLon2Pix((scanner.latitude, scanner.longitude))

        self.mapNodes[scanner.sensorid] = MapNode(scanner, coord[0], coord[1])

    # type: 4 --> changenode    ,   
    #((change, gem_ref, procentuele verandering ref), scanner object)
    def changeNode(self, sensorid, branchdata):
        self.mapNodes[sensorid].calcDanger(branchdata[2])

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        rect = self.contentsRect()

        #teken achtergrond
        self.realmap.drawRealMap(painter)

        #teken nodes
        for sensorid, mapNode in self.mapNodes.items():
            mapNode.drawMapNode(painter, self.realmap)


######################################################################

class RealMap:
    def __init__(self, path, coordRightTop, 
        coordLeftBot, width, height, pixpermet = 2.6):

        self.path = path
        self.coordLeftBot = coordLeftBot
        self.coordRightTop = coordRightTop

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.realdim = self.calcRealDim()

        self.pixpermet = pixpermet

    def drawRealMap(self, painter):
        image = QtGui.QImage(self.path)
        painter.drawImage(0,0,image)


######################################################################

class MapNode:
    dangertocolor = {"normal":"graphics//gradients//green.png",
                    "elevated":"graphics//gradients//orange.png",
                    "danger":"graphics//gradients//red.png"}

    def __init__(self, scanner, x, y, danger = 0):
        self.scanner = scanner
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.danger = 'normal'

        self.calcDanger(danger)

    def drawMapNode(self, painter, realmap):
        radiusm = self.scanner.range
        radiusp = radiusm*realmap.pixpermet
        factor = radiusp/200        # basis grootte gradiënten is 200 pixels.

        icon = QtGui.QImage("graphics//BT-icon.png")

        grad = QtGui.QImage(MapNode.dangertocolor[self.danger])
        grad = grad.scaled(grad.size().width()*factor, grad.size().height()*factor)


        painter.drawImage(self.x-100*factor,self.y-100*factor, grad)
        painter.drawImage(self.x-10, self.y-10,icon)
        painter.drawText(self.x-15, self.y+20, str(self.scanner.sensorid) + '-' + str(self.scanner.name))
```

An object is made through our application class:

```
    mapview = gfx.MapView(g_image)
    mapview.show()
```

So the first question is. What are we doing wrong in the paintEvent method?

**Secondly question**
Is there a way to make the paintevent not be called at EVERY RANDOM THING that happens ? (like mouseovers, etc)?

I tried something like:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    if(isinstance(event, QtGui.QPaintEvent)):

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        rect = self.contentsRect()

        #teken achtergrond
        self.realmap.drawRealMap(painter)

        #teken nodes
        for sensorid, mapNode in self.mapNodes.items():
             mapNode.drawMapNode(painter, self.realmap)
    else:
        pass
```

This 'works' but is to general I guess.. It actually makes the error appear a lot faster then without the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

When in your gfx.py you have:

```
    self.repaint(self.map.contentsRect())
    self.update(self.map.contentsRect())
```

Calling `repaint` and calling `update` one right after another is redundant.  And if a paint event comes through that handler and you call `repaint()` there, you are asking for infinite recursion.

Take note of any **Warnings** or **Notes** in the documentation.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#repaint

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent

I don't see the cause for your other error right off, but it probably has to do with QPainter getting used when it shouldn't...

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#begin

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#details

Hope that helps.

Comment: the 2 lines you mentioned were indeed a mistake.. They kinda got there by accident and aren't there in the real application ^^ - well only one is, the repaint. And I currently solved the repaint problem by setting a boolean in that handle 'needsrepaint' and when in repaint it checks it for true it repaints and then sets 'needsrepaint' to false. This removes the error I had.. (which was somehow caused from too much repainting I think)